# What are the rules for visa-free travel to France if it is followed immediately by a 90+ day visa?

Tags: immigration, visa, passport

I'm a US citizen. I'm planning to visit France this year for an exchange semester lasting 4 months. As my stay is going to be longer than 90 days, I was told to get a Long Stay visa (VLS-TS).

I'd originally booked my flight tickets for the 30th of August. These were the dates that I gave for my visa application, and so my visa is valid from 30th. Unfortunately, my airline has cancelled the original flight and rescheduled it to 29th. They're not agreeing to postpone, claiming that everything is booked up.

This is my question: Normally, US citizens planning to stay for less than 90 days would be able to travel visa-free to France. So, will I be allowed to enter France on 29th August despite my long-stay visa only being in effect from the next day?

Comment: You can definitely enter and stay before your long-stay visa, the only concern *could* be whether some official thinks you should leave again and reenter during the period of validity of your VLS-TS for it to be valid.